# Know how fast a Hard Drive is in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, wmi, hardware, hard-drive

I am writing a diagnosis program (like everest, but simpler) and I need to know how fast a HardDrive is. I wanna know things such as:

1 - Bytes per second (read)
2 - Bytes per second (write)
3 - S.M.A.R.T data

I guess I can use WMI to query such thing, but i have no idea how. It does not matter if I need to buy a component or get a opensource one. I also know that Windows Perfmoon is able to do that, but I cannot use it.

Comment: I don't hold an answer to this question but I think that read/write speed of hard drive is not the same for large and small files. Simple logic says that you should read/write some amount of data from/to HD and then divide size of data with time difference between end & start of operation (in seconds) to get proper read/write speed, respectively. For S.M.A.R.T data I don't have any idea.

Comment: Yeah, thats a simple way of doing that. But i guess windows have something ready to use.

Comment: Windows doesn't have anything built-in you can use from your code, AFAIK. It uses performance stuff for the hard disk to give the Windows Experience Index on Vista/Win7, but I don't know of any API that connects to that from your own apps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rafael to obtain the S.M.A.R.T data you can use the WMI or the Windows API.

**using the WMI**

the [`WMI classes to obtain S.M.A.R.T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463395.aspx) data are

- MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData
- MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictData
- MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus
- MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictThresholds
- MSStorageDriver_ScsiInfoExceptions

All are located in the `root\WMI` namespace. unfortunately these classes are not very well documented.

**using the WINAPI**

To access the S.M.A.R.T data from the Windows API requires a little more of work, you must use the [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions passing the respective structures to holding the data. you can find many sample of this on the [net](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/delphi/SMART.xml).

**To calculate the speed of a Hard Disk**

there is not a Windows api which expose directly this information. so you must calculate this your self. for an example you can check this application [`DISKSPEED`](http://home.earthlink.net/%7Ealegr/download/diskspeed.htm) which include the source code in C++. they uses the `CreateFile` function setting the [`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING ($20000000)`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99794) flag,  to make which any writes and read made to the file handle be done directly without being buffered.