# Determine Hard Drive Read/Write speed

Tags: performance, delphi, hard-drive

Given a C Drive, how can I create a temporary file to capture the disk write speed and then read read from it to determine the read speed? Then delete the file afterwards. I'm not sure if there's a WinAPI or library somewhere that can gather that kind of data.

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: no idea what to try or the best angle here. should i write a text file and fill it with random characters or try to create an image?

Answer (score 2):

Speed of the hardisk is influenced by multiple factors(OS, fragmentation of the disk, different installed programs and antiviruses, etc). You can start from this StackOverflow question [Know how fast a Hard Drive is in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558525/know-how-fast-a-hard-drive-is-in-delphi) which will give you an approximate speed of it.

Comment: Fragmentation, huh? It will influence a measurement, not the actual performance. Other listed factor are bogus too.

Comment: From the OP's question I believe he is trying to measure 'real' speed. And I believe that is influenced by the factors I mentioned. But he want that on the fly, so I suggested him to start from the question mentioned.